# Spring kafka retry call back is not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to implement spring kafka retry call back. Below is my code

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(this.kafkaConfigProperties.getConsumerConcurrency());
    factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
        LOG.info(" In recovery callback method !!");
        ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = (ConsumerRecord) context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD);
        Map conciseMap = (Map)record.value();
        //publisher.sendMessage((String)conciseMap.get("messagePayload"));
        ((Acknowledgment)context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT)).acknowledge();
        return null;
    });
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
    factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
    return factory;
}

RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(500L);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, Collections.singletonMap(RuntimeException.class, true));
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

But the call back is not happening. The log "In recovery callback method" is not getting printed. What could be the issue?

Spring kafka version used: 2.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging to get logs about retry progress.

Comment: @GaryRussell I tried adding `logging.level.org.springframework.retry=DEBUG` in application properties. But the log is not coming

Answer (score 0):

When using stateful retry, you need to add a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` to the container factory.

With the current version, that would be

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#stateful-retry).

Here's a complete app...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So60210116Application {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(So60210116Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So60210116Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
        factory.setRecoveryCallback(context -> {
            LOG.info(" In recovery callback method !!");
            ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record = (ConsumerRecord) context
                    .getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_RECORD);
            Map conciseMap = (Map) record.value();
            // publisher.sendMessage((String)conciseMap.get("messagePayload"));
            ((Acknowledgment) context.getAttribute(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.CONTEXT_ACKNOWLEDGMENT))
                    .acknowledge();
            return null;
        });
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, FixedBackOff.UNLIMITED_ATTEMPTS)));
        return factory;
    }

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
        RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
        FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
        fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(500L);
        retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);
        SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3,
                Collections.singletonMap(RuntimeException.class, true));
        retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
        return retryTemplate;
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "so60210116", topics = "so60210116")
    public void listen(String in) {
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so60210116").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so60210116", "foo");
        };
    }

}
```

With 2.2.x, use

```
factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
```

instead.

With 2.3 and later you can now eliminate the `RetryTemplate` with appropriate BackOff and recoverer configuration in the error handler.

Comment: but our current kafka version is 2.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: 2.2.6 is nearly a year old; you should try to keep up with the current version, at least within your minor release. The current 2.2.x release is 2.2.12. With 2.2.x, use `factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(Integer.MAX_VALUE));` instead (in my example above).